# Parent/child class constructor

Tags: java, android

I have parent class, and over 100 children, need to change all their constructors, is there any way to do it with one operation? Or I meed to go through all children and change them manually ?

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more info.. Can you give an example of one or two child classes; what do you want to change about them; etc..

Comment: Maybe try making a program that reads the file as a text file. Store the file names in an array and change each one using a for loop.

Comment: @LoganKulinski thanks I think that will help)

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need help with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I know there is no perfect way to do this task, but if your sub-classes(child classes)  are similar than you can write pattern-matching code and then you can replace code. 
            I have done this before, in my project I had to remove default constructor from all the classes, I did using Pattern Matching.for example How can I find constructor from code using pattern matching, I have to find some rules.

```
-> Will have no return type
-> Will have no parameter 
-> Name same as class name.
```

If Code will have function like this then it will have return type, so I think you can write pattern matching code.

Comment: thanks :) I think thats the only "easy" way to do it